# Understanding this symbol in C

Tags: c

What does the & mean in this code:

```
(number >> 9) & 0b111
```

I know about & in terms of pointers. But not sure how it works in the code above

Comment: Finding the meaning the operators on any programming language is relatively simple problem. You should try to research these on your own first, or you will have really hard times ahead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets break it down:

```
(number >> 9) & 0b111
  |     |  |  |   |
  |     |  |  |   Binary '7'*
  |     |  |  Binary AND
  |     |  Number to shift by
  |     Binary shift operator
  Variable
```

We'll start with the expression in the parenthesis:

```
(number >> 9)
```

This performs a binary right-shift by 9 places. For example:
`1101101010010011` will be shifted to become:
`0000000001101101`

The `&` symbol is Binary `AND`. Where the bits are both `1` in both of the source variables, the returned value will have those bits set:

```
  01101
& 11010
= 01000
```

So your code shifts your number by 9 places and performs `AND` on the result against `b111`.  As the three least significant bits are all set in the second input, the result of this operation will be the bits that are set in the bottom three bits of the shifted input.

Example:

```
 number =               1101101010010011
 number >> 9 =          0000000001101101
(number >> 9) & '111' = 0000000000000101
```

An alternate way of thinking about it is as follows:  The line extracts bits 10-12 and returns them as the result.

```
XXXXbbbXXXXXXXXX -> bbb
```

A common use for this is to apply a mask to a value to extract the bits. E.g. some libraries allow you to pass parameters with enumerable types like this:

```
set_params(option_a | option_b);
```

which sets both `option_a` and `option_b`.
Whether a parameter is set can be read by:

```
set_params(unsigned int params)
{
    if (params & option_a)
    { /* do option_a stuff */}
}
```

**assuming your compiler has a binary extension to the C spec. otherwise you could use `0x7` (hex 7) or just `7`*

Comment: As in my note at the bottom, I'm assuming your compiler (or the compiler of whoever wrote that line) has  a binary literal extension, in which case it would be the number `7` in binary.  Using `7` (decimal) or `0x7` (hexadecimal - better for larger numbers due to direct mapping of digits to bytes) would be preferable as it is portable.

Answer (score 1):

It is the *bitwise AND* operator.

More info here:
[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_.22.26.22)

Answer (score 1):

`&` is Bitwise AND

The C operators are here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B